# CKFinder integration ASP.net MVC complilation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor, ckfinder

I came accross a problem when integrating CKFinder for standalone use in ASP.Net MVC 3

I follow those steps:

1. Reference the CKFinder.dll in the project
2. Copy all the CKFinder files into my project(http://ckfinder.com/download, asp.net section)
3. Copy Standalone.aspx in the root of the project.

However, when I compile, many errors related to the attributs, they are doubled in AssemblyInfos.cs files

Example one of the error message: attribut guid is in double...

Do you have any ideas how to fix the problems ?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem - I resolved it by excluding the '_source' directory from the CKFinder root directory. Compiled with no problems.

I also added the 'System.Design' namespace as well...

Comment: @ed when i excluding _source its creating some other issue. _source folder is not necessary for mvc project ?